# What does "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'" mean when using built-in sum function?

Tags: python

I'm struggling to understand TypeError when using built-in sum function.

First, I would appreciate if you could check following function.

```
def mysum(*args):
    print(sum(args))
```

Second, I implemented following code.

```
mysum((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

So, following error was outputted.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

Thank you for reading this far.
It would be awesome if you could teach me this TypeError meaning.

Comment: Take out the extra parentheses

Comment: In other words, `sum(((1, 2, 3)))` is an error, `sum((1, 2, 3))` is not

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer

Answer (score 1):

When you define `def mysum(*args):`, python packs the function arguments into the single iterable "args" parameter. From the help text of `sum`

```
sum(iterable, /, start=0)
    Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers
```

Sum adds the values from the iterable to a start value that defaults to 0 (an integer). When you called `mysum`, args iterated a single tuple `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and python attempted to do `0 + (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`. You can add a print to the funciton to get a better idea of what's going on

```
>>> def mysum(*args):
...     print(repr(args))
...     print(sum(args))
... 
>>> mysum((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
((1, 2, 3, 4, 5),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in mysum
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

You could try a list to get a different view of the same problem

```
>>> mysum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in mysum
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

You could unpack the tuple in the call. The function will repack it into the `args` parameter

```
>>> mysum(*(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
15
```

And you can even redefine the start value and turn this into concatenation

```
>>> def mysum(*args):
...     print(repr(args))
...     print(sum(args, start=('a', 'b')))
... 
>>> mysum((1,2,3,4,5))
((1, 2, 3, 4, 5),)
('a', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> 
>>> mysum((1,2,3,4,5),(6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
('a', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to expand the argument with `*`, `sum()` itself expects list/tuple:

```
def mysum(args):
    print(sum(args))

mysum((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

If you need to specify arguments without the tuple (like `mysum(1,2...)`):

```
def mysum(*args):
    print(sum(args))

mysum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: I understanded argument sum function assumes thanks to you. And my struggling was solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A star with a name in the argument list groups positional arguments into a tuple. That means that calling `mysum((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))` creates a tuple for `args` with a single element, which is the tuple you're passing in. It's equivalent to doing the following within the function:

```
args = ((1, 2, 3, 4, 5),)
```

The error occurs because the default initial value for `sum` is the integer `0`. You can't add a tuple to it.

Two simple solutions present themselves. The easiest is probably to call the function with individual arguments:

```
mysum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

If you must pass in a tuple, drop the asterisk in the function definition:

```
def mysum(args):
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Thanks to you answer, my question is gradually getting clear. I'm struggling to understand new question. I would appreciate if you could teach me answer about next question. I'm going to upload question in an hour. I'll notify you here in an hour.

Comment: @MadPhycist I would appreciate if you could teach me my question , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64725417/why-status-like-a-happened.