# Why status like (A) happened?

Tags: python

Thank you for your reply.
My next question is following.

```
1: def mysum(*args):
2:     print(sum(args))
3: 
4: mysum(1, 2, 3)
5: 
6: print(sum((1, 2, 3)))
```

I understand that 4th line and 6th line are equivalent.

But 4th line in following code outputted TypeError and 6th line didn't output TypeError. ---(A)

```
1: def mysum(*args):
2:     print(sum(args))
3: 
4: mysum((1, 2, 3))
5: 
6: print(sum(((1, 2, 3))))
```

I want to understand why status like (A) happened.
I know you are busy, but I would awesome to teach me this.

Comment: Include the stack trace of your error, and make lines 4 and 6 the same (print / no print, sum/mysum)

Comment: @Zachary No, that difference is exactly the point.

Comment: Please add the actual errors. The error message will be informative

Comment: There are three differences between your lines. Only one of them causes an error. You should make them more and more similar, until you have one difference cause the error. (In this case, as mentioned by the answer, it's the extra parentheses)

Answer (score 1):

`mysum((1, 2, 3))` passes a tuple which gets collected in an `*args` tuple, so in the end you’re passing a tuple of tuples to `sum`, which it doesn’t know what to do with.

`sum(((1, 2, 3)))` is *not* a tuple of tuples, it’s just a tuple with grouping parentheses around it, which do nothing. It’s the comma that makes a tuple, not the parentheses. This would be equivalent: `sum(((1, 2, 3),))`